# Получить get параметры .htaccess и сделать редирект по ним

Tags: .htaccess

Есть сайт, на него ведут ссылки с utm метками (простые GET параметры в строке). Вопрос - как можно сделать редирект, исходя из условий по GET параметру?

Понимаю, что алгоритм примерно такой:

```
//получаем строку запроса

//выбираем необходимые данные (т.е. utm_* GET параметры)

//делаем условный оператор if() в .htaccess
```

Но как правильно это сделать? Впервые с этим сталкиваюсь именно в .htaccess.

P.s. версия апач 2.4, `<if>` поддерживает

Answer (score 1):

Документацию по директиве **if** можно прочитать [тут](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if).

Простой пример проверки наличия, например GET параметра **utm_one**, с помощью регулярного выражения (`\b` - граница слова, `[^&=]+` - проверка на наличие содержимого у параметра):

```
<If "%{QUERY_STRING} =~ /\butm_one=[^&=]+/">
  # действия выполняются при наличии utm_one
</If>
<Else>
  # действия выполняются при отсутствии utm_one
</Else>
```